# PDF generation using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to generate a report in pdf format, I have a foreach loop which is looping though the objects, for some reason the data is not being displayed on the downloaded pdf.
 any help is appreciated
here is my view page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Row No.</th>
        <th>Entry ID</th>
        <th>DC</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>ID No.</th>
        <th>Referance No.</th>
        <th>Entry Purpose</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Card No.</th>
        <th>Cabinets</th>
        <th>APC Card</th>
        <th>Key</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($assignees as $assignee)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->datacenter }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->cust->idnumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->custidno}}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->refnumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->entrypurpose}}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->timein }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->timeout }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->cardno }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->cabinet }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->apccard }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->key }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach

</table>
<div class="pull-right">
<strong> Report Generated on {{ date("d.m.Y") }} at {{date("h:i:sa")}}  </strong>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my controller:

```
public function downloadPDF($id){
      $assignees = assignee::latest();

      $pdf = PDF::loadView('assignees.pdf', compact('assignees'));
      return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

    }
```

Comment: You have no defined `$i` anywhere in the blade? It should be giving `Undefined variable: i ` error because of which PDF fails?

Comment: its a laravel blade, when using a foreach loop there is no need to predefine  the $i.
I am suspecting the issue is from the foreach syntax

Comment: You get `$loop->index` and not `$i` I believe as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops)

Comment: the $i field I have is being used as "row count" and not as the entry id. entry id can be found on the 2nd column of the table

Comment: Are you passing `$i` from controller to the blade, if not, then definitely doing {{ ++$i }} is not going to work. declare it first @php($i=1)

Comment: I have declared it.. the generated PDF is only showing the table headers.it is not going into the foreach loop.

Comment: Are you passing it the view properly?  What happens if you return the blade as a normal view, what errors do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 $assignees = assignee::latest();
```

Do:

```
 $assignees = assignee::latest()->get()
```

Because `latest()` returns a `QueryBuilder` object not a collection, you have nothing to loopthough. You need to call `get()` to execute the query and return a result.

Also, slight nit-pick: classes (assignee) should be cammel case starting in a capital letter according to PSR-2 which Laravel follows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
      <body>
        @if(count($assignees) > 0)
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Row No.</th>
                    <th>Entry ID</th>
                    <th>DC</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>ID No.</th>
                    <th>Referance No.</th>
                    <th>Entry Purpose</th>
                    <th>Time In</th>
                    <th>Time Out</th>
                    <th>Card No.</th>
                    <th>Cabinets</th>
                    <th>APC Card</th>
                    <th>Key</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach ($assignees as $assignee)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->datacenter }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->cust->idnumber }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->custidno}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->refnumber }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->entrypurpose}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->timein }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->timeout }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->cardno }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->cabinet }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->apccard }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $assignee->key }}</td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        @else
            <p>No data found!</p>
        @endif
        <div class="pull-right">
            <strong> Report Generated on {{ date("d.m.Y") }} at {{date("h:i:sa")}}  </strong>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update the blade to this and check  :

- There is a closing `</div>` tag missing after the `strong` tag at the end
- The $i is changed to `$loop->index`
- I have added a condition to check if data exists otherwise show `No data found!`

Comment: Thanks for your effort! unfortunately, I am still getting a table with the table headers only but no row data.. I have about 20 entries in my Assignee table.. all of them are showing just fine on a web page.